# Symfony display exceptions in prod environment

Tags: symfony

In prod env when error occurured symfony displays a standard error page.
This is the standard default framework error page:

[image]
But when PDO can't connect to database symfony display this error to the client:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known' in /homepages/35/d619429344/htdocs/mcg/web/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/35/d619429344/htdocs/mcg/web/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=db63...', 'dbo632759072', 'mgm_mgm', Array) #1 ...
```

PDO exeptions:

[image]

I can't display this error to the client for security reason.
Any ideas on how to disable these messages and redirect to an error page like other error ?

Comment: look this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732630/catching-database-exceptions-in-symfony2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have display_errors = off in your PHP.ini anyway to avoid this problem. Errors that reveal details like these come from many places, in addition to PDO.